# return class names not working in Jar

Tags: java

I have used this code to get a list of class names from a package:

```
private List<String> getClasses()
{
    List<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>();
    String packageName = "algorithm/impl";

    URL directoryUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
                        getResource(packageName);

    File directory = new File(directoryUrl.getFile());

    if(directory.exists())
    {
    String [] files = directory.list();
    for(String filename : files)
    {
        classes.add(filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf(".")));
    }
    }
    return classes;
}
```

but this does not work when the app is packaged as an executable jar file. Why?

Comment: Maybe you need to add some details about your code and what problem you're getting here.

Comment: because the package is not on the file system but inside the jar. So I need to read inside the jar. I am adding the list of class names to a drop down on a JOptionPane and the selected answer is used to create the required object. When it is jarred the list is empty as it didn't find the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of this class [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html).

```
JarFile file = new JarFile("YourFileName.jar");   
for (Enumeration<JarEntry> enum = file.entries(); enum.hasMoreElements();) {   
    JarEntry entry = enum.next();   
    System.out.println(entry.getName());   
}
```

Or if you want to search for particular class inside your jar you can use [ZipFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class.

```
                JarFile jar = new JarFile(YourJarFile);
                ZipEntry e = jar.getEntry(CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND);
                if (e == null) {
                    e = jar.getJarEntry(CLASS_FILE_TO_FIND);
                    if (e != null) {
                        foundIn.add(f.getPath());
                    }
                } else {
                    foundIn.add(f.getPath());
                }
```

Comment: thanks and I suppose I need to work out from that which ones are in the package I want.

Comment: @onesixtyfourth check the edited answer for searching a class name